# Jest: setTimeout is being called too many times

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, timer, jestjs, react-hooks

I am testing a `react` component that uses `setTimeout`. **The problem is that `Jest` is saying that `setTimeout` is called even though it clearly isn't.** There is a `setTimeout` to remove something from the ui and another one to pause the timer when the mouse is hovering over the component.

I tried adding a `console.log()` where the `setTimeout` is and the console log is never called, which means the setTimeout in the app isn't being called.

```js
//app
const App = (props) => {
  const [show, setShow] = useState(true);
  const date = useRef(Date.now());
  const remaining = useRef(props.duration);

  let timeout;
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Should not run');
    if (props.duration) {
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        setShow(false)
      }, props.duration);
    }
  }, [props.duration]);

  const pause = () => {
    remaining.current -= Date.now() - date.current;
    clearTimeout(timeout);
  }

  const play = () => {
    date.current = Date.now();
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    console.log('should not run');
    timeout = setTimeout(() => {
      setIn(false);
    }, remaining.current);
  }

  return (
    <div onMouseOver={pause} onMouseLeave={play}>
      { show &&
        props.content
      }
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
//test
it('Should not setTimeout when duration is false', () => {
  render(<Toast content="" duration={false} />);
  //setTimeout is called once but does not come from App
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(0);
});

it('Should pause the timer when pauseOnHover is true', () => {
    const { container } = render(<Toast content="" pauseOnHover={true} />);

  fireEvent.mouseOver(container.firstChild);
  expect(clearTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  fireEvent.mouseLeave(container.firstChild);

  //setTimeout is called 3 times but does not come from App
  expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

**So in the first test, `setTimeout` shouldn't be called but I receive that its called once. In the second test, `setTimeout` should be called once but is called 3 times.** The app works fine I just don't understand what is going on with `jest` suggesting that `setTimeout` is being called more than it is.

Comment: Still any solution here?...

Answer (score 8):

I'm experiencing the exact same issue with the first of my Jest test always calling `setTimeout` once (without my component triggering it). By logging the arguments of this "unknown" `setTimeout` call, I found out it is invoked with a `_flushCallback` function and a delay of `0`.

Looking into the repository of `react-test-renderer` shows a `_flushCallback` function is defined [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/962dfc2c33710b880d90ba8db4f531040077d48e/packages/scheduler/src/forks/SchedulerHostConfig.default.js#L49). The `Scheduler` where `_flushCallback` is part of clearly states that it uses `setTimeout` when it runs in a non-DOM environment (which is the case when doing Jest tests).

I don't know how to properly proceed on researching this, for now, it seems like tests for the amount of times `setTimeout` is called are unreliable.

Comment: Thanks for this; I used what you found to create a (hacked together) workaround, posted below.

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to @thabemmz for researching the cause of this, I have a hacked-together solution:

```js
function countSetTimeoutCalls() {
  return setTimeout.mock.calls.filter(([fn, t]) => (
    t !== 0 ||
    !String(fn).includes('_flushCallback')
  ));
}
```

Usage:

```js
// expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(2);
// becomes:
expect(countSetTimeoutCalls()).toHaveLength(2);
```

---

It should be pretty clear what the code is doing; it filters out all calls which look like they are from that `react-test-renderer` line (i.e. the function contains `_flushCallback` and the timeout is 0.

It's brittle to changes in `react-test-renderer`'s behaviour (or even function naming), but does the trick for now at least.